# Arithmetic operation in intra list elements

Tags: python, list

```
list =[1,2,3,4,5]
```

This is my list. Basically what i want to perform is, difference between all individual list elements, like `X=1-2-3-4-5`. How can I do it?

Answer (score 2):

The functional approach with a reduction:

```
from operator import sub
from functools import reduce

X = reduce(sub, [1, 2, 3, 4, 5])
```

Is basically equivalent to `((((1 - 2) - 3) - 4) - 5)`.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `reduce` to perform what you are asking.  It is built-in to python 2, but has been moved to the `functools` library for python 3.

```
from functools import reduce

a = [1,2,3,4,5]
reduce(lambda x,y: x-y, a)

# returns
-13
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try this:

```
givenlist = [1,2,3,4,5]
difference = givenlist[0]
for i in range(1,len(list)):
    difference = difference - givenlist[i]
print(difference)
```

It prints `-13`